# Is $X_t:=\int_0^t (B_s^2+3s+4)\,\mathrm d B_s$ a martingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a Brownian motion and $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ defined by $$X_t:=\int_0^t (B_s^2+3s+4)\,\mathrm d B_s.$$

Is $(X_t)$ a martingale w.r.t. the filtration of $(B_t)$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Simlply check the way I proofed  in my answer in [this other post of you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054738/martingale-property-of-a-given-function-w-r-t-filtration-given-by-the-brownian-m) that the processes is a martingale. It's working exactly the same here. You just have to use the moments of a normal distribution instead of the moment-generating function.

Comment: Can one also approximate the sequence method to find the martingale property ?